# Dealing with NaN’s in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a column that's generated from a custom component on the Data Flow in SSIS.
The data type of the column is float[DT_R8] that has along with valid float values, NaN's in there. I would like to identify these NaN's and treat(assign) these as NULL values.
I thought of doing something in the Derived Column Transformation like in the screenshot, but this didn't work.

[image: Derived Column Transformation]

It seems that in the Expression column, it can only be built from the functions available. But there isn't a 'isNaN' function that can be used.

[image]

Would you know of any other approaches, or how it can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `[numeric value] != [numeric value]`; if SSIS uses the normal floating-point rules, NaNs never compare equal to anything, including other NaNs. As an aside, even if you must use screenshots, take *screenshots*, not actual pictures of the screen. Screenshots tend to be inconvenient as it is if the problem can also be explained , but the low quality of photos adds insult to injury.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Your suggestion works! Re photos, there are restrictions on work pc's.